# Polymer Best Practices For Imports

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have seen this go back and forth in starter kits and I was wondering what is the best practice for importing element bower elements?

Should each element import the same bower packages redudntly? Or should there be be just one html sheet that imports all the bower elements?

Also, why is `<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">` always imported in each element regardless?

example- each element imports it's own elements, sometimes redudently(other elements may import these also):

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-image/iron-image.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="my-view1">
```

---

Or one html sheet importing all elements:

```
<!-- Iron elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/maps-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-form/iron-form.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-map/google-map.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-map/google-map-poly.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-map/google-map-marker.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-map/google-map-directions.html">


<!-- Paper elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/typography.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-textarea.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-radio-group/paper-radio-group.html">
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that with the establishment of the PPL pattern which got announced at Google I/) 2016, and the Polymer build mechanism, a basic structure emerged driven by Polymer CLI.

What I do depends on whether I am attempting to build a re-useable element or just one component which might be re-useable.  In a re-useable alement I always import `polymer` and just those elements that I have used within the element.  I reference everything via `../import-element/import-element.html`

With my own application I have a rule that tries to lazy load everything via `this.importHref` except that which is going to be on display when that element initially loads.  I have build a behavior for elements that include `iron-pages` so support that.  In this case I import `polymer`, any elements that will initially be on display.  I don't import the rest

html imports are de-duped by Polymer, so it doesn't matter if you attempt to load things more than once, they will only be loaded once.

In this case I reference the bower component elements with an absolute url `/bower_components/import-element/import-element.html` and for those in my app with relative urls.  I currently store ALL custom element for my app in the same directory, so to reference them I am using just `import-element.html`.  I think this last paragraph is **not** accepted practice, but I just find it easier not having to effectively map two physical directories to the same url.

Comment: HTML imports are deduped by the browser/polyfill. It's part of the spec. Once vulcanized though, they are not imports any more, right? Hence, it's possible to end up with multiple polymer.html etc.

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz I am using http/2 so I don't vulcanize anything - so no experience of that.

Comment: Sure HTTP/2 will make our lifes much easier :)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;**

I don't that solid best practice has emerged yet.

**Longer read**

My personal opinion is that import links are generally not a good idea at all, because you will run into trouble when bundling. Unless you want to bundle your entire application, in which case imports' location doesn't matter.

You may want to bundle related elements. For example there can be `<app-page-admin-panel>`m `<app-page-user-profile>`, etc. Each of them could be lazy-loaded the first time they are required. Bundled HTML imports don't give you such flexibility AFAIK.

If you bundle everything, there will be nothing to lazy-load of course.

If you create a bundle for each element loaded on-demand is a step forward but what about common elements? If both admin panel and user profile elements import `<paper-button>` would you include it in each bundle? This is probably safe, albeit wasteful wrt bandwidth. Polymer itself, however, cannot be imported multiple times. Thus importing it in each element is probably not a good idea.

**Possible future solution - ES6 module imports**

Personally I very much hope for ES6 imports. With `import "polymer"` you are safe, because bundled or not, it will be guaranteed by the module loader (and browser in the future) that you will only ever import it once. You may want to see my answer to that other question: [Modules in Polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690653/modules-in-polymer/39697214#39697214).

Comment: Just to add to this... In the the Polymer Start Kit which is now part of the Polymer-CLI each element you write imports it's own dependencies rather than having one `elements.html` file. This means that when the build is generated, each of your elements is bundled with it's own dependencies. If a dependency has already been imported in another element, it won't be bundled as it already exists. You can then even look at asynchronously importing your elements for performance improvements.